# Analytics Studio Shows a Blank Row with the Highest Count on LightningInteraction Dataset

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring, crm-analytics, analytics-studio

Having two questions on the Lens created based on LightningInteraction dataset in Analytics Studio.

1. The highest count row for COMPONENT_NAME bar shows the component name as blank. Does anyone knows what that means? We can filter that and see others but given the blank name is showing the way higher count than all others, we can't just ignore it.
   [image]
2. COMPONENT_NAME shows as concatenation of multiple components. Anyone knows what it means and anyway to break it down further? Below is the way it shows the component name in the Lens if I add it to one of the Bars.
   e.g. *c:comp_A;c:comp_B;c:comp_C*

Answer (score 0):

1> You can try using [PAGE_URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightninginteraction.htm#:%7E:text=1471564788642-,PAGE_URL,-Type)/PAGE_ENTITY_TYPE/TARGET_UI_ELEMENT to get more context where component name is missing.

2> A Lightning page represents a customizable screen made up of regions containing Lightning components. All the components that were loaded when the user navigated to a record will be listed. [COMPONENT_NAME](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightninginteraction.htm#:%7E:text=example%3A%2096.43.144.26.-,COMPONENT_NAME,-Type) is the internal name of the component that the user interacted with. The Salesforce developer assigns the names when the components were created.
You can look at creating a multivalue field from this using [Split](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_recipe_multivalueFunctions.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=SYNTAX-,split,-Splits%20a%20string) function in recipe so that you can use COMPONENT_NAME in filters or groupings. You can also update the component names via [AuraDefinitionBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_auradefinitionbundle.htm).